# Resonance curves for coupled pendulums

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coupled-oscillators

I'm looking for the resonance curves of coupled pendulums (a) and coupled spring pendulums (b). 
[image: pendulums]

The background:
I want to find analogies for the oscillating curcuit as for inductive coupled ones I found that the resonance frequencies split up:[image: resonance curve]

And I assume that the coupled pendulum (b) shows a beat?

Comment: Seems like you want a mechanical oscillator analogue to the two weakly coupled electronic resonant circuits that you drew, but offhand I don't see how it is apparent that either of the two mechanical oscillators you drew fits that requirement. I would start off by drawing two independent mechanical oscillators (using either springs or pendulums), and then introduce some weak coupling between the two mechanical oscillators by means of, say, a weak spring. That would be more clearly analogous to the coupled electronic circuit that you sketched.

Comment: Yeah sure. Do you have a resonance curve of two pendulums coupled by a weak spring?

Comment: Don't see a plot of a frequency versus amplitude for two coupled pendulums offhand, but it appears to be a well-known problem that has been worked out by many so you can easily find the equations describing the motions and plot up a frequency versus amplitude graph yourself. Just google "two coupled pendulums".